# How to corrupt xfs/ext4 metadata

Tags: linux, filesystems, xfs, pxe

I want to develop a system that repairs corrupted xfs/ext4 file system automatically using pxe rescue. To do so, I need to reproduce fs corruption several times during developing. It's nice that xfs_repair or fsck can always fix the issue correctly.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 2):

Trash randomly selected filesystem metadata blocks. Trashing occurs to randomly selected bits in the chosen blocks. This command is available only in debugging versions of `xfs_db`. It is useful for testing `xfs_repair(8)` and `xfs_check(8)`.

For example

```
xfs_db -x -c blockget -c "blocktrash -s 512109 -n 1000" /dev/xfstest/testfs
```

Comment: It works as I expected! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## ext4

This worked for ext4.

```
# break superblock
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb1 bs=10000 skip=0 count=1

# check
parted -l

# repair 
fsck -n /dev/sdb1
fsck -y /dev/sdb1

# Try this if fsck does not work
mkfs.ext4 -S /dev/sdb1
fsck -y /dev/sdb1
```